# Why are my loops not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the colour of a paragraph from red, to blue, to green. The multiple loops I have tried were unsuccessful, and I have listed one of them below.

Edit: 
I realize I made a huge mistake in this code and that’s why it’s not looping. Forgive me. It is going to green right away because of the way I made the code.

```js
var one = document.getElementById("titleTwo");


for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
  one.style.color = "red";
  one.style.color = "blue";
  one.style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learn to Code!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="titleOne">Welcome to...</p>
  <p id="titleTwo">Coding Club!</p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should learn how to use the javascript console. Its essential for javascript debugging.

Comment: `one.delay is not a function` Plus others...

Comment: How do I use the console? Can you please link me a source that can help me? @chevybow

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `delay()` is a jQuery function. It is not valid in plain Javascript. Also, `delay()` function works for delaying animations, not style attributes!

A plain Javascript solution would be to use `setInterval` to execute a function every time interval (e.g. every 500 ms like I did):

```js
var one = document.getElementById("titleTwo");

setInterval(changeColor, 500);

function changeColor() {
  var color = one.style.color;
  if(color == 'red') { one.style.color = 'blue'; }
  else if(color == 'blue') { one.style.color = 'green'; }
  else one.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
  <head>
        <title>Learn to Code!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="titleOne">Welcome to...</p>
    <p id="titleTwo">Coding Club!</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: @Stocker Well, the snippet works fine on my browser. And `setInterval` keeps executing until you call `clearInterval`. I don't see why this wouldn't work, make sure you included this code correctly in your JS.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try again. Edit: it’s working! Idk what happened I’ll double check.

Comment: @Stocker Glad this worked for you! If this solution helps, please consider upvoting/marking as answer.

Comment: Sure! And also I’m new to stack, any thoughts on why I’m getting downvotes?

Comment: No idea, your question is well-expressed, and shows an attempt. And I don't know why my own answer got downvoted either..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `delay()` isn't a function! In JavaScript, you can use `setTimeout(functionname, milliseconds, arg1, arg2, arg3...)` to set a delay. Hope this is helpful!

[Javascript-Delay](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-delay-a-JavaScript-function-call-using-JavaScript)

Comment: Or a `setInterval` - why using `setTimeout` in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with a loop, but css:

```
<style> 
   @keyframes altercolor { 
      0% {color: red} 
      50% {color: blue} 
      75% {color: green}
      100% {color: red}
   } 
   .altering-color { 
      animation: altercolor 2s infinite; 
   } 
</style>

<p id="titleTwo" class="altering-color">Coding Club!</p>
```

Comment: The `infinite` property keeps it going forever. Did you use it?

Comment: I copied the code exactly, but I may have done something wrong, so I’ll try again and let you know.

Comment: I also think the loop is not the problem, it’s my code.

Comment: I tested it in this sandbox and it worked: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic

Answer (score -1):

`one.delay` won't delay anything,  since it isn't a pre-made JavaScript function. Use `setTimeout(function, time);` where time is in milliseconds. Also, use `one.style.color()` to set colors. It isn't the `for` loop, it's the code INSIDE the loop.

`setTimeout()` [explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: `one.style.color()` is not a valid JS function!

Comment: Also, why using `setTimeout` in a loop? You can use `setInterval` instead

Comment: I have used one.style.color = “color” to change color, and it works fine (except for the loop part).